# Path traversal vulnerability in http.FormFile

Tags: go, http, security, multipartform-data, checkmarx

I have a Go http handler which is responsible for uploading files (with content-type multipart/form-data) and copying them to some target path.
A simple variation looks more or less like this:

```
func uploadHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var targetFile *os.File
    targetFile, _ = os.OpenFile("./my-test-file", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0644)
    file, _, _ := r.FormFile("file")
    io.Copy(targetFile, file) 
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

My code is is scanned by Checkmarx and I keep receiving the following error:

> " ... gets dynamic data from the FormFile element. This element’s value then flows through the code and is eventually used in a file path for local disk access in func at line X. This may cause a Path Traversal vulnerability.

As I am not using the path\filename I do not really understand how path traversal attack can be exploited in this code.

Even though, I still tried to perform different verifications on the fileName (cleaning, taking only the base, checking the extension, and checking for links etc.) and even change it in the request, but all attempts were in vain.

I thought that maybe it can be exploited if the file has a .zip extension for example and contains paths within its content. Can this be the issue?

#### Update

When trying to replace the io.copy() call with the following code:

```
    body, _ := io.ReadAll(file)
    targetFile.Write(body)
```

The Checkmarx scan suddenly passed. From my point of view, this change is only cosmetic, right?

As if there was any vulnerability in the first place, reading the dynamic data into a temporary var and then writing it to the targetFile from the temporary var should still have the same vulnerability.

Can this new information spill some more light and help me reach a real solution or determine whether this is a false positive?

Comment: Impossible to tell without actual code. Might be a false positive.

Comment: @Volker thanks for the quick comment. Actually this is more or less the actual code - I removed the error handling and a bit unrelated business logic for simplicity. Other than that this is all I have.

Comment: Updated my question with some new info

Comment: Seems as if this checkmarx is overeager and maybe not worth the trouble.